# Marketplace App Icon Usage

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons

When submitting a Windows Phone 7 app, you need to include the following icons:

- Large Mobile
- Small Mobile
- Large PC

Once listed on the market, the Large PC icon is displayed in the Marketplace on both the phone and PC - different style icons were used for each. What are these other icons used for?

Here is an image to clarify what we are seeing:
[image: Notice the "mobile" icons do not show up in the phone]

Comment: did you submit this as a bug to MSFT? if so, what were the results?

Comment: @Otaku no, I don't think we have. I don't have access to the windows phone account for our team, but I will post updates to this question if we get a response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 6 images to be concerned about, but given pixel dimensions of two of them being the same, you *could* use just 5 images.

```
#  Image        Where Used?                   Size (Pixels) File Type Require/Option 
1. Small mobile Phone Marketplace catalog     99 x 99       PNG       Required
2. Large mobile Phone Marketplace catalog     173 x 173     PNG       Required
3. Large PC     PC Marketplace catalog (Zune) 200 x 200     PNG       Required
4. Background   Background panorama           1000 x 800    PNG       Optional
5. App Icon     In the app list on the phone  62 x 62       PNG       Required
6. App Tile     In the start page on the phone173 x 173     PNG       Required
```

Notes:

1. 1-4 are for selling/marketing your
   app. 1-2 are shown in the
   Marketplace on the phone and 3 is
   shown in Zune. #4 - I believe it is
   shown on both phone/Zune.
2. 5-6 are used once the app is
   installed. These are to be listed your WMAppManifest.xml as `<IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>` and `<BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>` respectively.
3. 2 and 6 are the same pixel size, so they
   *can* be the same, if that's what you want. I've done that.
4. You *can* use transparency on #6,
   but don't use it on any other image.

Comment: The issue we're seeing is with Icons 1, 2, and 3 - the other icons work as expected. I've posted a clarifying image to the question.

Comment: Have you used transparency on the first 2 icons' green color (#1 and #2 in my list)? I've installed it and you did use transparency on #5 and #6 in my list.

Comment: 5 & 6 use transparency, but nothing else does.

Comment: This is either a bug in the Marketplace, in which case you need to get in touch with MSFT, or there is something wrong with the 2 images. Can you post those 2 images somewhere, like Dropbox?

Comment: No, I'm not able to post the full-res icons, but I highly doubt anything is at issue with them. We'll double check them and if nothing comes up we'll get in touch with Microsoft about it.

Comment: Okay, if they were originally created for another platform, like iOS, try running them through the WP7 Image Converter tool. The deep link is http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/media/1281/wp7imageconverter.zip (built on ImageMagick). The main website is http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com, but I can't find the link directly off of those pages.

Comment: They were created specifically for WP7, from scratch. Thanks for that link though.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse the marketplace in the Zune software on the PC you'll see the 2 different size icons being used. The larger size is used in the list at the top of the page and the smaller size in the "we recommend" and "new apps" sections.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to verify this without being either a new or featured app?

Comment: @Jake if you want to verify it you could start Fiddler (or similar) then open the Zune desktop client. This would allow you to verify that different images were being used—but not which ones.