# Windows Phone Icons Explained

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I was reading [this very useful article](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/gg317447) and noticed that a Windows Phone application needs many different icons. The article listed these:

1. Marketplace_Desktop_200x200.png
2. Marketplace_Device_173x173.png
3. Marketplace_Device_99x99.png
4. Application_TileImage_173x173.png
5. Application_IconImage_62x62.png

> > note: each image should be changed in the properties to have build == content

Then I noticed that when I pin my application to the start, the icon was wrong. So I copied the Application_TileImage_173x173.png over the Background.png in the root of my project. But now when I pin my application to start, the icon is completely blank. Grr!

So, I hit a frustrating wall here:

- What is the purpose of each of those sizes? Should they all be in the project?
- Where is the right location for each of those sizes? An /Images folder?
- Where is the correct reference to any of those sizes in the proj props?
- And, sort of an aside, should screenshots also be included in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Either use the same name as the ones in your root (Background.png and ApplicationIcon.png) and then just copy them over from Windows Explorer (say yes to overwrite existing) or **2)** go into WMAppManifest.xml and replace those names with your own images' names and then add them and make them `Content`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5860417/353716

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I'll include Screenshots in any App  I release, however, they are not necessary.  They are simply available for users to view the app before purchase.

As to the images:
- Background.png (173x173) must be in the root directory, it must be a .png and it must be included as "content".  This icon is the Icon shown when pinned to start.
- ApplicationIcon.png (62x62) must be in the root directory, it must be a .png and it must be included as "content".  This is the icon displayed while in the application directory.

Now, as to making sure everything loads appropriately, verify by right clicking on the project name and selecting "properties", then select the "Application" tab.  In this tab you should see several option make sure "Icon" is set to "ApplicationIcon.png" and "Background" is set to "Backgorund.png".  also define the tile properties here as well.